# JQuery: Datatables - Column Filtering Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, filtering

I'm attempting you the plugin found here (http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html) on my datatables that are populated via AJAX, but when following the instructions in the example for adding the required footer to the table:

```
<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

I wind up simply with a footer row w/labels and not the text boxes as shown in the example.

Any thoughts on what I need to do to correct this?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you add a `th` for each column ? Does the footer match the header ? In the example source there is a `theader` in the beginning of the table, with the exact columns as the footer. Perhaps that is a requirement.

Comment: Yes, I have a matching header, but still no luck.

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net with your view source ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to you .datatable javascript?

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        $('#example').dataTable()**.columnFilter()**;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance.  I wound up trying a few different locations for the location of the  $('#example').dataTable()**.columnFilter()**; call, and since I'm using AJAX, I needed to have it positioned during the rendering of my table.

Something such as:

```
if( typeof dataTable == 'undefined' )
dataTable = $('#eventRecords').dataTable({"bJQueryUI": true}).columnFilter();
```